# Why do Asagi's eyes change color?

Tags: strike-the-blood

Normally, Asagi seems to have reddish-orange eyes, but under certain circumstances they change to a bright red color. This happens, for instance, when she is hacking into the Nalakuvera. The change is a bit subtle and I'm not even sure if it's intended or if it's just a combination of different lighting and inconsistent animation, but it is at least noticeable. Here's a comparison shot with the two most extreme examples I could find:

[image: difference in eye colour]

Is this change actually occurring or is it an animation error? If it is real, what is the meaning behind her eyes changing color?

Comment: It must be a side effect of activating her "supah hakkah powahs!"

Comment: Is she actually a vampire? I just finished watching the series myself and there seems to be two vampires at the end, Reina and Moegi. We know for a fact that Reina confirmed Kojou + Yukina as her parents because she outright said it. Then she also has Hasta Aurum as a familiar / weapon. Moegi on the other hand never referred to Kojou as her father, so perhaps her Asagi is a vampire married to someone else?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong there. Her eyes are red, and because of the sun, they look reddish-orange. Here is a link that will tell you everything about her:  http://strike-the-blood.wikia.com/wiki/Asagi_Aiba

On that site, it says her eyes are red.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the second season, she is the Cain Priestess (the impersonation of the Itogami island). So it is the visual effect of waking her power up for being able to hack an unhackable (great example is when she fought against Lydianne Didier (The Tank Rider) in the second episode of the second season). Then also author told us that Asagi is the Cain Priestess directly.